# Spring mvc submit form not found error 404

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc and I have created a jsp page.

**redmn.jsp**

```html
<form id="forma" name="forma" action="something" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    //some fields
 <input type="submit" value="Valider" />

  </form>
```

Then I have created one controller to handle my request:

```
@Controller
public class SecondController{


@RequestMapping(value="/something", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String addRes( HttpServletRequest req,
        BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
 // some treatements
 return "redmn"
}
```

When I am clicking the submit button, I am getting 404 error. Please someone help to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is your context path??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing context path. In order to get correct request path you should append context path.

if you are using spring tag lib

```
<spring:url var="something" value="/something"></spring:url>
```

If you are using jstl

```
<c:url var="something" value="/something"/>
```

and then in your form tag specify action

```
 action="${something}"
```

Comment: even if including the : <%@taglib prefix="f" uri="springframework.org/tags/form"%>; <form:f> isn't recognized. it shows this warning "Unknown tag (form:f)".

Comment: @hamzaspecter use should use `<f:form> ` not `<form:f>`

Comment: this one is working, i should be focusing in the 404 error. thanks

Comment: @hamzaspecter Also include `<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>` and the above solution will work for you

Comment: After including the tag : it isn't working for me, im still getting 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

When you have POST method, in the JSP you should add modelAttribute

```
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="something" action="${something}">
```

In your controller the things should be this way:

```
public String saveOrUpdateUser(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User user,
    BindingResult result, Model model) {
//...
}
```

Further information about handling you could find in this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-example/