# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'parametre'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I'm working with spring MVC, so Basically im creating a forum wich will take a file and radioButton as Input:
form_li.jsp:

```spring
<f:form  id="form1"
         name="form1"
         modelAttribute="parametre"
         action="${addTreat}"
         method="POST"
         enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>xslx File : </td>
            <td>
                <f:input id="filepd" path="fileCom" name="filepd"  type="file" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Choice </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <f:input id="az" name="az" path="choice" type="radio" value="false" />
                    <label for="az">1</label>
                    <f:input id="aj" name="aj"  path="choice" type="radio" value="true"/>
                    <label for="aj">2</label>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <div align="center">
                <f:input type="submit" value="Validate" path="" />
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
</f:form>
```

for myController :

```spring
@RequestMapping(value="/addTreat", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTr(HttpServletRequest req,
        BindingResult result,
        ModelMap model,
        @RequestParam("parametre") Parametre parametre) {

    model.addAttribute("parametre", new Parametre());
    return form_li;
}
```

for the class Parametre.java:

```spring
public class Parametre {

    private String choice;
    private MultipartFile fileCom;
    //getters and setters
    //default constructor
}
```

my problem is when running the application and going to the /addTreat url. im getting the famous Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'parametre' available as request attribute. i have tried multiple solutions but i doesn't work. please can anyone help to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

So many things are messed up here, I recommend you to read some `modelAttribute` examples, there are dozens, even on the official spring documentation. It looks like you confuse model object with simple request param, for the second one you don't even need `BindingResult`. Also the syntax of your form action is incorrect.

`action="${addTreat}"` change to `action="/addTreat"`

Comment: without the `action="${addTreat}"` im getting error 404.
for the modelAttribute i've been throwgh multiple tutoriels, i don't know where im missing the point.

Comment: @hamzaspecter I think you don't accept the fact that issue you have posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35915201/spring-mvc-submit-form-not-found-error-404 is resolved by specifying that. I see you have a very less acceptance rate, thats why I haven't even interested in posting in answer.

Comment: @Bazz It has nothing to do with action

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera i'm sry my friend, i've forgotten to accept it as solution.